# Quartus 2 verliog using curly craces to set particular bits

Tags: set, verilog, bit, quartus

Hi I am new to verilog and I try to set some particular bits from one reg variable to another reg but it didn't work for me. what am ı doing wrong?

```
reg [31:0] a;
reg [31:0] b;

initial begin
 a =32'b0;
 b =32'b1;
 $display("current value of a = %32b ",a);
 a ={b[5:0]};
 $display("value of a %32b ",a);
 #10 $finish;
 end
```

bit of a from a[0] to a[5] should be 1 but only a[0] became 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you code `b = 32'b1` yields `{31{1'b0},1'b1}`, so only `b[0]` is equal to one.

In SystemVerilog (check: [IEEE1800-2012, 5.7.1 Integer literal constants](http://www.ece.uah.edu/~gaede/cpe526/2012%20System%20Verilog%20Language%20Reference%20Manual.pdf)) you can use automatic left padding of constant literal numbers using a single-bit value, i.e. `b = '1` to set all bits of `b` to one.

Using Verilog, simply assign another value to `b` (i.e. `b = 32'b11111`) or change your code to following:

```
a[4:0] = {5{b[0]}}
```